# RxJS example of loading and enriching a list of items

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to fetch an array containing multiple items and then fetch and add additional data to every item in that array.

How can I implement the method `getEnrichedItemsList` given the  implementations for `getItemsList` and `getRelatedObject`?

```ts
interface RelatedObject = {}

interface Item = {
  id: string;
  relatedObjectId: string;
}

interface EnrichedItem = Item & {
  relatedObject: RelatedObject ;
}

interface apiService = {
  getItemsList: (query: string) => Observable<Item[]>; // implemented
  getRelatedObject: (relatedObjectId: string) => Observable<RelatedObject>; // implemented
  getEnrichedItemsList: (query: string) => Observable<EnrichedItem[]>; // HOW TO IMPLEMENT?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
  getEnrichedItemsList(query: string): Observable<EnrichedItem []>{
    return this.getItemsList(query).pipe(
      mergeMap(items => from(items)),
      mergeMap(item => this.getRelatedObject(item.relatedObjectId).pipe(
        map(relatedObject => Object.assign(item,{relatedObject}))
      ))
    );
  }
```

Full example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ahllnu

Comment: toArray() at the end of the pipe and that it! thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking forward and had I noticed the comment above by @blazkovicz, I would have saved 20 minutes of not trying to figure out switchScan and last combination.

Answer (score 3):

Use `forkJoin` to execute multiple requests simultaneously and emit an array of items with the same order as the input array.

```ts
getEnrichedItemsList(query: string): Observable<EnrichedItem[]> {
  return this.getItemsList(query).pipe(
    switchMap(items => forkJoin(items.map(item => this.enrichItem(item))))
  )
}

enrichItem(item: Item): Observable<EnrichedItem> {
  return this.getRelatedObject(item.relatedObjectId).pipe(
    map(relatedObject => ({ ...item, relatedObject } as EnrichedItem))
  )
}
```

This guarantees that the final order of enriched items is the same as received by `this.getItemsList(query)` which may not be the case when using `from` and `mergeMap`.