# Use Observable instead of Promise to map an array of objects

Tags: angular, dictionary, promise, rxjs, observable

**Problem**:
When I fetch data from the server I get some object in the format:

```
{
  list: {
    pagination: {},
    entries: []
  }
}
```

I need to go through entries and change them. To change them I need to call some REST API for each entry (for example: in the first call I will get ids, and for each id, I need to get real data). After all REST calls are finished for each object I need to change its data. so entries[i] = from id to real data.

I resolved the problem with Promises but I want to do that with Observables.

I tried to use map and concatMap from rxjs but without success.

**Code**:

```
public getUsers(queryBody?: SearchRequest): Observable<PersonPaging> {
    const searchRequest =
      queryBody ||
      this.searchService.makeSearchRequest(
        new Query({ type: ContentModel.TYPE_PERSON })
      );

    return this.searchService
      .search(searchRequest)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(async (resultSetPaging: ResultSetPaging) => {
          const users: PersonPaging = {
            list: {
              pagination: resultSetPaging.list.pagination,
              entries: []
            }
          };

          for (const rowEntry of resultSetPaging.list.entries) {
            const { properties } = rowEntry.entry;

            const personEntry = await this.getUser(
              properties[ContentModel.PROP_USERNAME]
            ).toPromise();

            const person: Person = personEntry.entry;
            person.avatarId = this.getUserAvatarImage(person);

            users.list.entries.push(personEntry);
          }

          return users;
        })
      );
  }
```

**END OF QUESTION**

CODE IN PROGRESS:

```
  return this.searchService.search(searchRequest).pipe(
      map((resultSetPaging: ResultSetPaging) => {
        return from(resultSetPaging.list.entries).pipe(
          concatMap(rowEntry => {
            const { properties } = rowEntry.entry;
            return from(
              this.getUser(properties[ContentModel.PROP_USERNAME])
            ).pipe(
              map(personEntry => {
                const person: Person = personEntry.entry;
                person.avatarId = this.getUserAvatarImage(person);
                return { person };
              })
            );
          })
        );
      })
    );
```

With this code, I get all users with modified data but I don't get the object that I want with pagination. And it's call x times (x - number of users/entries)

Comment: This [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64290137/1858357) should help you.  It doesn't deal specifically with pagination, but shows how you can return a combined set of data from multilple http calls. [StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64284681?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure how you expect this to be formatted, but this should get you close. It sounds like all you really need to do is reduce your list of `Person` into an array on `users.list.entries`? That would look something like this:

```
return this.searchService.search(searchRequest).pipe(
  map((resultSetPaging: ResultSetPaging) => {
    return from(resultSetPaging.list.entries).pipe(
      concatMap(rowEntry => {
        const { properties } = rowEntry.entry;
        return from(
          this.getUser(properties[ContentModel.PROP_USERNAME])
        ).pipe(
          map(personEntry => {
            const person: Person = personEntry.entry;
            person.avatarId = this.getUserAvatarImage(person);
            return { person };
          })
        );
      }),
      reduce(
        (users, personEntry) => {
          users.list.entries.push(personEntry);
          return users;
        },
        {
          list: {
            pagination: resultSetPaging.list.pagination,
            entries: []
          }
        }
      )
    );
  })
);
```

or maybe slightly cleaner (it's the same thing though)

```
return this.searchService.search(searchRequest).pipe(
  map((resultSetPaging: ResultSetPaging) =>
    from(resultSetPaging.list.entries).pipe(
      concatMap(rowEntry => {
        const { properties } = rowEntry.entry;
        return from(
          this.getUser(properties[ContentModel.PROP_USERNAME])
        );
      }),
      map(personEntry => {
        const person: Person = personEntry.entry;
        person.avatarId = this.getUserAvatarImage(person);
        return { person };
      }),
      reduce(
        (users, personEntry) => {
          users.list.entries.push(personEntry);
          return users;
        },
        {
          list: {
            pagination: resultSetPaging.list.pagination,
            entries: []
          }
        }
      )
    )
  )
);
```

---

Aside: I also wonder if your very first map, works as expected. It looks like you're returning a stream, so you might want mergeMap instead?

```
map((resultSetPaging: ResultSetPaging) =>
  from(resultSetPaging.list.entries).pipe(...
```

to

```
mergeMap((resultSetPaging: ResultSetPaging) =>
  from(resultSetPaging.list.entries).pipe(...
```

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you so much. There are so many rxjs things that I am learning.

I needed mergeMap at the end as well.

What I need to change is 
`(users, personEntry) => users.list.entries.push(personEntry),` to `(users, personEntry) => { users.list.entries.push(personEntry); return users; }`, because push returns number, and accumulator need to be as seed.

Comment: Good catch with reduce's accumulator function. I'll update my answer.